# Django session cookie forgotten on every browser reopen - mobile Safari (iphone,ipad)

Tags: ios, django, session, cookies, safari

I wonder if anybody encountered with this problem. I am storing some data about visitor in django session. It works as expected but only mobile safari (iphone and ipad) have strange behaviour.
When I visit my site from iphone or ipad(Safari ver. 14.3) session cookie is normally set. But when I close the browser then reopen, new session cookie is generated.
This behaviour can be seen only on mobile safari version. I was not able to reproduce it on macOS desktop safari.

To solve this problem I had to change setup for session cookie in django **settings.py:**

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = ‘None’
```

[According to django doc. cookie is normally set as ‘lax’ and this introduce security risk in my app.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE)

> SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE
>
> Default: 'Lax' The value of the SameSite flag on the session cookie.
> This flag prevents the cookie from being sent in cross-site requests
> thus preventing CSRF attacks and making some methods of stealing
> session cookie impossible. Possible values for the setting are:
>
> - 'Strict': prevents the cookie from being sent by the browser to the target site in all cross-site browsing context, even when following a
>   regular link.
>    For example, for a GitHub-like website this would mean that if a
>   logged-in user follows a link to a private GitHub project posted on a
>   corporate discussion forum or email, GitHub will not receive the
>   session cookie and the user won’t be able to access the project. A
>   bank website, however, most likely doesn’t want to allow any
>   transactional pages to be linked from external sites so the 'Strict'
>   flag would be appropriate.

> - 'Lax' (default): provides a balance between security and usability for websites that want to maintain user’s logged-in session after the
>   user arrives from an external link.
>    In the GitHub scenario, the session cookie would be allowed when
>   following a regular link from an external website and be blocked in
>   CSRF-prone request methods (e.g. POST).

> - 'None' (string): the session cookie will be sent with all same-site and cross-site requests.

> - False: disables the flag.

I guess that I had to cause security hole in my django app intentionally. I don’t like it but I am not sure how serious risk it is. I would love to know why only mobile safari behave like that.

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading Django 2.0 to 2.2. Now I've set SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE=False and the issue seems solved. This issue occurs not only in Safari, but on iOS's Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I guess so, Firefox and Chrome must use Safari as render engine on IOS. So I guess there must be same issue. Thank you.

Comment: And I have another website based on Django 2.1, which also sets `SameSite=Lax` session cookie flag. And it doesn't lead to this issue on iOS for some reason.